# Jupyter Notebook - run cell and save as .py file

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I know of the `%%writefile .py` cell-magic command but it causes the cell to not run. What I want is for the cell to run and create the .py as well.

Edit 1: I only want the original code in the cell to be saved as a .py file. I don't need the results

Comment: `.py` file can keep only code but not result of running this code - can't keep values which it will have in variables after running code - so saving it after running code will give the same result as saving it without running.

Comment: @furas Sorry, I think I wasn't specific enough. I only want the code in the cell to be saved as .py. Nothing related to the results. Updated my question

Answer (score 2):

I would try to:

1. Use the `%%writefile` magic in *the next* cell, referencing the last one

or

2. Use the `%save` line magic instead.

Comment: 1. How do I reference the last cell this way?
2. %save doesn't work for the current cell. It uses line numbers which doesn't fit my needs

Comment: `%%writefile hello.py`


`print("hello World")`

It worked for me in local Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to deal with it.
Follow two ideas:

1. **%%writefile** in the first cell followed by **%run yourscript** or **!python 'yourscript.py'**
2. Convert your code into a string, run it with **exec** and save it.

The first option is the most common, and you can pass arguments. The second option can be attractive because you don't depend on a Jupyter Notebook to use it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the magic function `%xxxxx` at the top of the cell.

- To write the **cell's content**:

`%%writefile cell_to_file.py`

If **append** is desired, just add **-a**: `%writefile -a filename`.

- To write **all notebook's content** up to that cell:

`%save notebook_to_file.py`

The output file will be stored in the same directory as the notebook. Here is the [documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html). Good luck!